# How to use ROS and STM32F767ZI?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm currently building an underwater robot (AUV), I want to use STM32F767ZI to control the motor automatically using ROS melodic, but I don't know how to use it, I really beg you to help me, thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376984/how-to-use-ros-and-stm32f767zi-?/) by [HSN](https://answers.ros.org/users/73750/hsn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2021-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

Using ROS Melodic, you should take a look at ROSSerial https://github.com/yoneken/rosserial_stm32, run this on the board and then connect to your high system computer over serial (Duh).

If you're not constrained to the ROS distro, then I'd highly (very highly) suggest you move to ROS2 and use micro-ros https://micro.ros.org/ which is quite documented and better supported. You'll run micro-ros on the board and connect to the higher system over your desired transport protocol. However, as you'll be running on an STM32F767ZI, you should have access to ethernet. Ethernet is much more a reliable protocol than serial.

Good luck

---

Originally posted by [bjv-capra](https://answers.ros.org/users/73753/bjv-capra/) with karma: 26 on 2021-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HSN](https://answers.ros.org/users/73750/hsn/) on 2021-04-27**:
thank you very much, for now I will try as you suggest and if there are problems I will come back here for a consultation, have a nice day